# Get .tsv file from an archive in java without unzipping the archive

Tags: java

I have an archive `_2016_08_17.zip` that contains 8 .tsv files. I need to extract the file named `hit_data.tsv` and upload it to bigquery. The files are in a bucket on the google cloud platform.

Can someone give me a simple program that opens the archive, finds the correct file and then prints its rows to screen. I can take it from there. My idea is to replace the path `gs://path_name/*hit_data.tsv` with the buffer that contains the `hit_data.tsv` data.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pipeline p = DataflowUtils.createFromArgs(args);

    p
            .apply(TextIO.Read.from("gs://path_name/*hit_data.tsv"))  
             \\.apply(Sample.<String>any(10))  
            .apply(ParDo.named("ExtractRows").of(new ExtractRows('\t', "InformationDateID")))
            .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                    .named("BQWrite")
                    .to(BigQuery.getTableReference("ddm_now_apps", true))
                    .withSchema(getSchema())
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));

    p.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, you can't read a file from a zip archive without unzipping it.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't want to access the hard drive more than I need to. I can certainly access the file without saving the unzipped file on the hard  drive.

Comment: sure, but that's not what you asked - you should update your question to clarify

Comment: I tried to ask it in the way that makes the most sense. I think that you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

We have [ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class. It has [entries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries()) method that returns enumeration of entries. Now we can find entry or use [getEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry(java.lang.String)) method if we know name and path to file in zip.

Then, last step, we can use [getInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream(java.util.zip.ZipEntry)) method to read only entry that we want.